HTTP500 - Having problems returning data that is inserted into database when sending post request
I'm sending a post request to my database/listings/initUser. Using SQLlite/Cloudflare D1 database. Just to confirm that /listings/getAll is working. However, /listings/initUser isn't properly working. Any solutions? Thanks
"message": "D1_ERROR: near "@gmail": syntax error at offset 79",
export interface Env {
    DB: D1Database;
  }
  
  export default {
    async fetch(request: Request, env: Env) {
      const { pathname } = new URL(request.url);
  
      if (pathname === "/listings/getAll") {
        // If you did not use `DB` as your binding name, change it here
        const { results } = await env.DB.prepare(
          "SELECT * FROM listings"
        )
          .all();
        return Response.json(results);
      }
      if (pathname === "/listings/initUser") {
        const {access_token, refresh_token, email, address, password, profileImgLink, creditScore, first_name, last_name}: {access_token: string, refresh_token: string, email: string, address: string, password: string, profileImgLink: string, creditScore: number, first_name: string, last_name: string} = await request.clone().json();
        const queryOne = `INSERT INTO auth (email, password, access_token, refresh_token) VALUES (${email}, ${password}, ${access_token}, ${refresh_token})`;
        const authPrep = await env.DB.prepare(queryOne).all();
        return Response.json(authPrep);

}```

